# Capture / Read message displayed in the Excel Application status bar

Tags: vba, excel

I have created VBA code that updates an Excel sheet, refreshes the Data Connection and saves the Excel sheet.

**The problem :** while the Data connection is still getting refreshed, the VBA code moves to the next step of Saving the Excel, and a pop-up prompting the user to Cancel the refresh appears (which it shouldn't because the refresh has to happen and a user input defeats the purpose of the VBA code). Below is a snippet:

```
 wkb.Connections("Connection2").Refresh
    While (InStr(1, Application.DisplayStatusBar, "Running background query") > 0)

    Wend
 wkb.Save
 wkb.RefreshAll
    While (InStr(1, Application.StatusBar, "Running background query") > 0)

    Wend
 wkb.Save
```

[image]
**Question :** How can I capture this text in the Status  Bar so that I can wait till it disappears? 
*Application.StatusBar does NOT do the trick.*

Comment: Would a `DoEvents` command rather than a `While..Wend` loop work?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/118468

Comment: The simplest solution is to turn off the background query option in the connection properties, if it is available.

Comment: Your first one is checking for whether the status bar is displayed `While Application.StatusBar = "testing ddddddd": DoEvents: Wend`

Comment: `Application.statusbar` only returns text that was displayed in the (left corner of the) status bar using code. At all other times it simply returns `False`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few things to try:

1) Go to the connection properties and uncheck "Enable background refresh". It should wait for the refresh to end before executing your next line of code. Or in code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
```

2) Try the method CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

```
Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").Refresh
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

If you're working in Excel 2010 or later it should wait until this is all done.

3) Possible third option, just a DoEvents command

```
Connections("CONNECTION_NAME").Refresh
DoEvents
```

Comment: Alex D's answer was very helpful but I'm looking at ways to grab the status bar text. I will post back if I find a way.